# Run Hasura without Docker

Tags: docker, hasura

I'm looking for the way to run Hasura without Docker, but can't find any way to do that - is there any option to achieve that?

Have a negative experience with Prisma in Docker, would like to try Hasura, but no, please, no Docker.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run the GraphQL Engine as a binary by building the Haskell executable with Cabal following the instructions here:

https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/blob/master/server/CONTRIBUTING.md#run-and-test-manually

You'll need to download and install GHC 8.6.5 and Cabal, which if you read the instructions, can be done using `ghcup`:

https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/

After following the previous instructions to compile, you can run the engine without Docker with the following:

```
cabal new-run -- exe:graphql-engine \
  --database-url='postgres://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>' \
  serve --enable-console --console-assets-dir=../console/static/dist
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it! It's a pleasant surprise to meet one more Haskell project live!

Will it also build the web part, making it a complete project, or will it be only an engine?